# Local composer dependencies

Tags: php, git, symfony, configuration, composer-php

I've got following situation: I have two composer projects - one depends on another. These are Symfony application and bundle that it's dependent on. Both are tracked by git, I've got also remote repositories for them.
I work on both projects locally and commit & push changes to remotes when I'm done.
I also work in a team, so everyone in a team has his own OS and local directory structure.

For now I've got my bundle vendor directory symlinked to the another directory that's somewhere on disk. It's doing right because I can freely work on my bundle and test it inside of the host application in real time as I'm making changes.

The problem starts when I need to change dependencies of my bundle. I change composer.json inside of it and I need to update these dependencies on host application and develop further. My configuration doesn't allow me to do that, when I do 'composer update' on host application, it of course tries to update from remote (as it is defined in composer.json) and it sees old composer.json version so none of bundle dependencies are visible to it.
Also I don't want to push untested dependencies to remote.

Did anyone have this kind of issue? Is there a way to handle it somehow without need to push untested changes just to update them on a host?

Comment: Just clone into the appropriate directory - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18130386/778719

Answer (score 1):

If you work in team and your teammates also need this feature you can just set up your own Packagist server that will be able to track your packages. Also you will have control on versions of your library. And all of your teammates will need only `composer update` after your changes.